# Mongoose findOne and save new document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a list of users that has 'hobby' object inside it.

```
User: {
   name: John Doe,
   hobby: {
     [{hobby_id: 77777, hobby_name: hockey, hobby_type: sports}],
     [{hobby_id: 88977, hobby_name: singing, hobby_type: talent}],
    }
   age: 27
}
```

now i want to findOne the user and add new hobby on the list. my first try is:

```
 var user = User.findOne({ _id : req.body.user_id});

 User.update(user, { hobby: [{ hobby_name: req.body.name , 
                               hobby_type: req.body.type }] }, 
              function(err, user){
                if(err){
                  return res.status(500).json(err);
                }else{
                  return res.status(200).json(user);
                }
              });
```

however, with this code, everytime i call the function, my "NEW" hobby replaces the first one.

what can i do?

Comment: I could be wrong but your object structure also seems a little off.  Should be closer to:

User: {
   name: John Doe,
   hobby: [
     {hobby_id: 77777, hobby_name: hockey, hobby_type: sports},
     {hobby_id: 88977, hobby_name: singing, hobby_type: talent},
    ]
   age: 27
}

Comment: `User.findOne` is an async operation, you can't use `user` object immediately after calling `findOne`, you should do that in callback or use promises. Because of that you can't find user, and your code just updates first object in users collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to do the same.

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.user_id, {$push:{ hobby: [{ hobby_name: req.body.name , 
                               hobby_type: req.body.type }] }}, {safe: true}
              function(err, user){
                if(err){
                  return res.status(500).json(err);
                }else{
                  return res.status(200).json(user);
                }
              });
```

And here findByIdAndUpdate is do both finding and updating the same document. no need to use callback or promises. Please refer the following [link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using whe repalce syntax, rather than the update syntax.  I think you need:

```
user.hobbies.push({ hobby_name: req.body.name , 
                           hobby_type: req.body.type })
```